# XAML inconsistent binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a custom UserControl called `ReferencedItem`. It should take a Guid called ItemId. It is implemented as such:

```
private static void OnItemIdChanged(DependencyObject dobj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dpArgs)
{
    //Do something
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemId", typeof(Guid?), typeof(ReferencedItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
    // use an empty Guid as default value
    Guid.Empty,
    // tell the binding system that this property affects how the control gets rendered
    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
    // run this callback when the property changes
    OnItemIdChanged
));

public Guid? ItemId
{
    get { return (Guid?)GetValue(ItemIdProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemIdProperty, value); }
}

public ReferencedItem()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel = new ReferencedItemCtrlViewModel();
    DataContext = ViewModel;
}
```

The `ItemsSource` will be made up of `Reference` objects defined as:

```
public class Reference
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now when binding this `ReferencedItem` the value is not set as intended. Here is the code I want to work, but does not bind as intended:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ReferenceStack" ItemsSource="{Binding References}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ReferencedItem ItemId="{Binding Id}" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have tried:

```
 <local:ReferencedItem ItemId="128d48f0-f061-49fb-af49-b8e4ef891d03" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

This works as expected, the `OnItemIdChanged` method is triggered.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Id}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="90"/>
```

This works as expected, a label is rendered with the Id.

Is there something I'm missing here? From what I can tell the data is available at bind time -- it just doesn't bind under the exact conditions I need it to :)

Thanks for any input!

EDIT:

Here is the code-behind for `ReferencedItemList`, the first block of XAML posted above:

```
public partial class ReferencedItemList : UserControl
{
    protected ReferencedItemListCtrlViewModel ViewModel;

    public ReferencedItemList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new ReferencedItemListCtrlViewModel();
        DataContext = ViewModel;
    }

    public void Load(Guid id, string name)
    {
        ViewModel.Load(id, name);
        //ReferenceStack.ItemsSource = ViewModel.References;
    }
}
```

The commented line has been experimented with in place of the `ItemsSource="{Binding References}"` that was defined in the XAML.

I don't think I can successfully post the code for `ReferencedItemListCtrlViewModel` without going down a rabbit hole -- needless to say it has a property `References` of type `ObservableCollection<Reference>` where `Reference` is defined earlier in this post.

ReferencedItem.xaml:

```
<v:BaseUserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</v:BaseUserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image x:Name="LinkIcon" Visibility="{Binding HasReference, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ToolTip="View Referenced Item" Source="/Images/link.png" Height="18" MouseUp="LinkIcon_MouseUp"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ReferencedObjectDesc" Text="{Binding ReferenceHierarchy}" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: *"the value is not set as intended"* - you didn't show the user control (xaml, constructor, etc.). More likely you are playing with its `DataContext` inside, this is why binding doesn't work. Check binding errors in Output window.

Comment: That was helpful - it gave me further insight into the issue. The only modification I did to the DataContext was assigning it to the ViewModel to be used -- and it has all properties that I'd expect to be present. 

I think it boils down to: why does the binding work on the Label but not on the ReferencedItem? When I checked the console output, it had the following error:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Id' property not found on 'object' ''ReferencedItemCtrlViewModel'

Which is helpful - but why is Label using a different object and binding correctly?

Comment: Are you saying that somewhere in your code you are setting the user control's DataContext? Can we see that bit of code?

Comment: Correct - I've updated my post to include the code-behind for where I set the DataContext. It also gave me the chance to read over my original post which I've cleaned up a bit since it was typed out in a hurry. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does the Xaml look like for your `ReferencedItem`?  Can we see its code-behind too?  Are you setting `ItemId` anywhere in your code-behind, and possibly clearing the binding?

Comment: I've added `ReferencedItem.xaml` to the bottom of my post, minus the namespaces and such. The code-behind is the first block where I've added the constructor that alters the DataContext. Same style as ReferencedItemList. I've cut out 4-5 methods that aren't relevant - click events and similar.

Comment: I should add on - I have not done anything with `ItemId` within `ReferencedItem` yet -- my goal was to get the data in first before implementing anything so I'm pretty confident I'm not clearing it elsewhere.

Comment: Apologies for the spam - figuring continuous comment edits would be odd. It seems that the issue is setting the DataContext for `ReferencedItem` inside of it's constructor is the problem - it binds `ItemId` after the constructor has executed, effectively undercutting the DataContext prior to binding. It's progress - but also leaves me unsure of how to provide a DataContext to `ReferencedItem` while simultaneously "passing" the `ItemId` to the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to post the answer (explanation) I came across.

The problem was changing the DataContext of my `ReferencedItem` user control in the constructor. The view would instantiate a `ReferencedItem` and alter the DataContext - so once it was time to bind I had already flipped the context from the intended `Reference`.

There are multiple ways to resolve the timing - all project dependent. Either avoid setting the DataContext all together, set it post binding, or change the context on other items as appropriate.

*Much thanks to [Sinatr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr), [Andrew Stephens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981831/andrew-stephens), and [Mike Strobel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/175070/mike-strobel) for all mentioning this at one point or another -- just took me some time to actually reach it. I don't think there's a way to assign credit to a comment, but let me know if there is.*